# is there a read_delim way to read column names from the last line of a file

Tags: r, readr

I have an application which produces pseudo csv output that is intended to import into Excel.

The major quirk is that this file format doesnt always contain the complete list of column names at the start of the file.  The application exporting the csv file appears to "discover" the columns while it is doing the exporting of the data.

Fortunately, the application does print the complete list of column names at the very end of the file.

**Question:** Is there a way to get read_delim (and other family functions) to use a line other than the first one, as the line that names the columns - ie. in the example below, so that columns **extra1** and **extra2** are named instead of X1, and X2 ?

sample data:

```
#client version: blah
#Message event data
# Period start time: 1619666820000000000 (Thu Apr 29 2021 13:27:00.000000000 AEST)
# Period end time: 1619675221000000000 (Thu Apr 29 2021 15:47:01.000000000 AEST)
#Format:
time,ts_ns,src,src_port,dst,dst_port,bytes,application,id,values
="2021-04-29 13:27:00.006289581",="1619666820006289581","172.30.2.70",58280,"10.2.139.5",19901,160,"appName",="1614910529214246156",0.111713
="2021-04-29 13:27:00.013557400",="1619666820013557400","172.30.2.70",55920,"10.2.139.7",19902,160,"appName",="1614910529214271438",0.102003
="2021-04-29 13:27:00.015840285",="1619666820015840285","172.30.2.70",55910,"10.2.139.7",19902,160,"appName",="1614910529214348545",0.099041
="2021-04-29 13:27:00.020072322",="1619666820020072322","172.30.2.70",58276,"10.2.139.5",19901,160,"appName",="1614910529214260360",0.095228
="2021-04-29 13:27:00.021587125",="1619666820021587125","172.30.2.70",55936,"10.2.139.7",19902,160,"appName",="1614910529214338698",0.095754
,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,
="2021-04-29 13:27:00.021587125",="1619666820021587125","172.30.2.70",55936,"10.2.139.7",19902,160,"appName",="1614910529214338698",0.095754,"blah1","blah2"
time,ts_ns,src,src_port,dst,dst_port,bytes,application,id,values,extra1,extra2
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is a some default argument/setting in any of the functions which will allow you to directly do this but you can do some post-processing after reading the file.

```
#Read the file without header
data <- read.table('file1.csv', sep = ',')
#Assign column names from the last row of the data
names(data) <- unlist(data[nrow(data), ])
#Remove the last row
data <- data[-nrow(data), ]
#Change the data to default types
data <- type.convert(data, as.is = TRUE)
```

You may need to add `skip = n` in `read.table` if you want to skip first `n` rows while reading the file.